# How do I flush NSLog's buffer?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have error handling code like this:

```
if (ERROR) {
   NSLog(@"<some message>");
   exit(-1);
}
```

The message logged with NSLog doesn't always appear in the console, presumably because exit() terminates the process without flushing NSLog's buffers.  How can I flush NSLog's buffers myself?

Comment: Just a blind guess, but how about `fflush(stdout)` just before you `exit`?

Comment: NSLog prints to stderr I think...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if (ERROR) {
   NSLog(@"<some message>");
   fflush(stderr);
   exit(-1);
}
```

But you should not use `exit` in production code because [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27) say it clearly:

> **Never quit an iOS application programmatically** because people tend to interpret this as a crash. However, if external circumstances prevent your application from functioning as intended, you need to tell your users about the situation and explain what they can do about it. Depending on how severe the application malfunction is, you have two choices.

Comment: Just to be clear he can use the fflush, what he can't use is the exit() function.

Comment: fflush is for buffered data.   stderr doesn't buffer data.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
[someMessage writeToFile:@"/dev/stderr" atomically:NO 
      encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: That would probably have the same issue, unless you send YES instead of NO to atomically. Can't test right now though...