# NSString to NSDate is NOT working when called multiple times

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.6

I have written this function in a class:

```
- (NSDate *) convertDate : (NSString *) dateStr{
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
  [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
  NSDate *dateFrmStr = [[NSDate alloc] init];
  dateFrmStr = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
  return dateFrmStr;
}
```

I am calling this function in another class like this:

```
NSString * dateStr1 =@"01-01-1977";
NSString * dateStr2 =@"22-12-1977";
NSString * dateStr3 =@"19-01-1978";

MyClass *data = [[MyClass alloc]init];

NSDate *dateObj1 = [data convertDate:dateStr1];
NSDate *dateObj2 = [data convertDate:dateStr2];
NSDate *dateObj3 = [data convertDate:dateStr3];
NSLog(@" >>> dateObj1 %@",dateObj1);
NSLog(@" >>> dateObj2 %@",dateObj2);
NSLog(@" >>> dateObj3 %@",dateObj3);
```

When I run this the only first date seems to get converted because the output I get is :

```
>>> dateObj1 1977-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

There is no error nothing but the programs just stops.

Comment: NSLog is doing some buffering internally. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546742/how-do-i-flush-nslogs-buffer) out.

Comment: It's not necessary to do 'dateFrmStr = [[NSDate alloc] init]', because your very next line changes dateFrmStr. Just initialize dateFromStr to nil.

Comment: How come the second and third log statements are not printed? Is the program interrupted?

Comment: There is nothing wrong that can prevent from logging. as @EightyEight said it may buffering issue from NSLog.  If you are not using ARC release the dateFormatter before returning from convertDate: Also there is no need to allocate dateFromStr object as dateFormatter returns an autoreleased one.

Comment: Yes I changed the code like this                                        NSDate *dateFrmStr = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateOfBirth];          Yes the program gets interrupted. I tried catching the exception but there is none. I am using ARC.

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint on the second or third log statement and then try to step into it?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried you're code and for me works very fine( with ARC ), probably you're issue is somewhere else in "MyClass"…
BTW! Why don't you make a "category" on NSDate?

Something like this :

### NSDate + ConvertDate.h

```
@interface NSDate (ConvertDate)

+(NSDate *) convertDateFromString : (NSString *)dateString;

@end
```

### NSDate + ConvertDate.m

```
@implementation NSDate (ConvertDate)

+(NSDate *)convertDateFromString:(NSString *)dateString{


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

}

@end
```

---

Yes it looks like your code, the only differences are that you don't need to allocate an instance of "MyClass" to use the
"convertDateFromString" method because you're using a class method.'

Comment: I've tried again and again… it works… so like i've said before… probably your program stops somewhere else… maybe you're doing something between the first "convertDate" and the second…    if you can paste some of your code… maybe we could help you better...

Comment: You are correct actually in the sense that the code works for dates other than dates that fall between 01-01-YYYY to 01-02-YYYY. All I am trying to check is find if dateObj1 falls between dateObj2 and dateObj3. my code is here   if (([dateObj1 compare:dateObj2] != NSOrderedAscending) && ([dateObj1 compare:dateObj3] != NSOrderedDescending)){
        NSLog(@" >>>>>> Found in the date range.");
        
    }else{
        NSLog(@" >>>>>> NOT found in the range.");
    }

Answer (score 0):

could it be

NSString * dateStr2 =@"22-12-1977";

that NSDate thinks 22 as the month??? maybe try 12-22-1977 instead?? i usually use NSDateFormatter to convert to string or date..

Comment: I am also using the NSDateFormatter PLease See the original post  for code. YOu will see the date format is @"DD-MM-YYYY" is being set.

Comment: you are right! why dont you put a debug line on first NSLog... but examine the values for dateObj2 and dateObj3..? see if they have proper value in it..